# Is there a way to find all tests associated with a specific class on any level?

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, code-analysis

I'm using Intellij IDEA to program a project in java. I'm trying to test a class which I've changed and I want to get a list of all the tests that use it on any level.

Is there a way to do it in Intellij? Any external tool apart from IDEA can be good too.

I know how to get the direct unit tests(That's possible using CTRL+SHIFT+t) but I also want other tests as well that test the class on more complex level).

I want to find tests that might use the class C as follows:

Test A runs class B which uses class C.

So I want to find Test A and other like it.

Comment: Edit the constructor to throw an exception, run all tests and look at the failing ones?

Comment: That's a clever idea actually. But what about static methods or if there are other classes which might already be broken.

Comment: No idea, I'm don't use java. I sort of assumed your tests passed already. Throw exceptions from your static methods as well? Otherwise you're going to need some sort of code coverage tool, which in my experience (from C#) tend to cost money.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I'm sure there is some good open source alternative for code coverage..

Comment: Unfortunately there is no implemented tool in IDEA providing such a functionality.